# What WinXP tool displays graphs of server statistics?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003

I have domain admin rights on my computer. I once used a tool which was part of Windows XP that allowed me to see any server's CPU, RAM and other states in graph form. What tool was it, and how can it be accessed?

Comment: This question on ServerFault might have what you are looking for. http://serverfault.com/questions/19553/view-task-manager-type-display-remotely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance Monitor allows you to log and/or graph all sorts of local and remote system counters.